# all commands in raspbian terminal stop working

Tags: raspbian, linux, bash

I run Raspbian. Everything worked fine until now, when it seems I can't use any command on my Raspberry Pi. I tried to reboot. And now it doesn't connect to wifi.

> @raspberrypi: sudo su
>
> -bash: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file

also:

> @raspberrypi ~ $ ls /usr/
> Segmentation fault

After connecting to a display, I get the following log. (ilustrated in a picture)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to re-image the SD card.

You seem to have serious corruption.

Any idea what caused the problem?

Comment: well, I don't have a clear idea. I get alot of "Segmentation fault" errors, when recording using a Raspicam and cancel the execution. I ignored them. But i don't think this would have been the problem.

Comment: I should have checked that you get the same problem with commands after re-boot.  Or is it just a wifi problem after re-boot?

Comment: after reboot my raspberry doesn't work anymore. I will connect it to a display to see if raspbian boots.

Comment: This isn't necessarily because of fs corruption, but I agree you might as well start over again by re-installing the OS.   I also recommend you use [the most recent Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) if that isn't what you have.   It wouldn't just be cancelling execution either, although that is a puzzling statement since something that segfaulted is already dead and cannot be cancelled.  Unfortunately diagnosing it via online Q&A is not very feasible, so you will have to settle for mysterious.